# How can I catch five consecutive numbers in an array of int[5] in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I wrote this little program that catches five integer numbers that are entered consecutively at the console. 
This works as expected - **except for one thing**:
I did not find a way to accept 0 as one of the numbers being entered.
Of course, a solution with another collection type is easy.
But the challenge here is to do it with an array of five integers.
I tried to set a boolean flag "zeroEntered", tried with a counter, tried to count j backwwards. It all does not work.
Perhaps this is not possible? Would somebody know for sure?
Here is the code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    #region Catch5IntegerInArrayOfInt[5]
        // I try to catch five integers in an array of int[5] 
        // This works as expected except I cannot catch 0 as one of the numbers
        // Cannot wrap my head around this one it seems
        // because all ints are initialized with 0
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter five unique numbers consecutively.");
        int[] fiveNumbers = new int[5];          // do it using an array just the same (as collections were not part of the lectures so far)

        for (int i = 0; i < fiveNumbers.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your {0} number:", (Countables)i);
            CatchUsersNumbers(fiveNumbers, i);
        }

        DisplayResult(fiveNumbers);
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
    }
    #endregion

    #region HelperMethods
    private static bool CheckWhetherInteger(string userInput)
    {
        bool result = Int32.TryParse(userInput, out myInteger);
        if (result == false)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("You did not enter an integer.");
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static bool CheckUniqueness(int[] fiveNumbers, int userInput)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < fiveNumbers.Length; i++)
        {
            if (userInput == 0)
            {
                for (int j = i ; j <fiveNumbers.Length; j--)
                {
                    if (j == 0)
                        break;
                    if (fiveNumbers[j] == 0)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
             }
            else if (fiveNumbers[i] == userInput)
            {
               return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static void CatchUsersNumbers(int[] fiveNumbers, int i)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            userInput = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
            if (CheckWhetherInteger(userInput) && CheckUniqueness(fiveNumbers, myInteger))
            {
                fiveNumbers[i] = myInteger;
                break;
            }
            else
                Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("You did not enter a unique integer number, try again...");
        }
    }

    private static void DisplayResult(int[] fiveNumbers)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Array.Sort(fiveNumbers);
        Console.WriteLine("These are the five interger numbers you entered \nand that were stored in the array:\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < fiveNumbers.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i != fiveNumbers.Length - 1)
                Console.Write(fiveNumbers[i] + ", ");
            else
                Console.Write(fiveNumbers[i]);
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Class Variables
    private static int myInteger = 0;

    private static string userInput;

    private enum Countables
    {
        first = 0,
        second,
        third,
        fourth,
        fifth
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: As a matter of good practice, never iterate a loop from 1 to arraySize + 1. Arrays are 0-indexed, people are used to this. If you need to print out the correct number, add one to *it* instead of the iteration variable

Comment: I just did it in this case because of the enum I use and because I found it funny if first would be indexed 0, etc. But probably you are right, as it occurred to me already. However, the problem is a different one.

Comment: I corrected it - now the array is zero-based and the enum starts at 0 too. Also corrected the case of one method name.

Comment: `Catch` is a keyword relating to exception handling in C#. I'd suggest you choose another word in your title and question to avoid misunderstanding: 'parse'? 'read'? 'get' etc.?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but your array of 5 ints will be initialized to 5 zeroes, so when scanning for uniqueness, your check fails, especially because of this piece of code:

```
if (fiveNumbers[j] == 0)
{
  return false;
}
```

So instead of looping through the entire array, you should keep a counter to keep track of how many items you already have in your array. Then, when performing the check, only check upto that index, and don't include the other items in the check, because they contain 0, but you should treat them as uninitialized.

You could also solve this using other data types. For instance, you could create an array of nullable integers, so you can actually check whether an item already got a value. Or (maybe the best solution) you could use a List instead of array.

Comment: Hi - thank you - using nullable integers really is the solution, as I would not want to keep a counter when entering numbers into the array. I completely overlooked this, or let's better was I wasn't aware. I post the correct version should s.b. else be interested.

Answer (score 0):

Your Only error here is that int.TryParse() takes 0 as invalid you could make another if statement to handle the exception but this looks less clean

```
 private static bool CheckWhetherInteger(string userInput)
{
    if (userInput == "0")
    {
       myInteger = 0;
       return true 
    }
    else
    {
        bool result = Int32.TryParse(userInput, out myInteger);
        if (result == false)
            {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("You did not enter an integer.");
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Hi - thank you for taking a glance. I integrated the change you suggested, but it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Sorry I thought the problem was in the tryparse() but it seems it was as you posted in the Array being initialised with zeros XD

Answer (score 0):

I just post the solution - using nullable integers - as suggested by Golez Trol. Here it is, should somebody be interested:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    #region Catch5IntegerInArrayOfInt[5]
        // The solution to catching five integers in an array of int[5] 
        // is to use nullable integers.
        // Keeping a counter when entering an integer to the array does not appeal to me.
        // With normal integers I cannot catch 0 as one of the numbers
        // because all ints are initialized with 0
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter five unique numbers consecutively.");
        var fiveNumbers = new int?[5];          // do it using an array just the same (as collections were not part of the lectures so far)

        for (int i = 0; i < fiveNumbers.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your {0} number:", (Countables)i);
            CatchUsersNumbers(fiveNumbers, i);
        }

        DisplayResult(fiveNumbers);
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
    }
    #endregion

    #region HelperMethods
    private static void CatchUsersNumbers(int?[] fiveNumbers, int i)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            userInput = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
            if (CheckWhetherInteger(userInput) && CheckUniqueness(fiveNumbers, myInteger))
            {
                fiveNumbers[i] = myInteger;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("You did not enter a unique integer number, try again...");
            }
         }
    }

    private static bool CheckWhetherInteger(string userInput)
    {
            bool result = Int32.TryParse(userInput, out myInteger);
            if (result == false)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("You did not enter an integer.");
            }
            return result;
    }

    private static bool CheckUniqueness(int?[] fiveNumbers, int userInput)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < fiveNumbers.Length; i++)
        {
            if (fiveNumbers[i] == userInput)
            {
               return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static void DisplayResult(int?[] fiveNumbers)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Array.Sort(fiveNumbers);
        Console.WriteLine("These are the five interger numbers you entered \nand that were stored in the array:\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < fiveNumbers.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i != fiveNumbers.Length - 1)
                Console.Write(fiveNumbers[i] + ", ");
            else
                Console.Write(fiveNumbers[i]);
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Class Variables
    private static int myInteger = 0;

    private static string userInput;

    private enum Countables
    {
        first = 0,
        second,
        third,
        fourth,
        fifth
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Thank you for your hints - I was truly stuck.